# How do you dismiss the previous view controller or a controller that I want from another view controller?

Tags: swift, viewcontroller, presentviewcontroller, dismissviewcontroller

I want to dismiss a view controller that is not currently on top.

I present a view controller and when I present it I want the previous one closed.

To give more details, this is the path I follow A -> B -> C when I reach the C I want B to be closed.

Comment: Need more context, you mean only ViewController A and C will be left? Or only C?

Comment: If it is possible i just want to close B i mean A and C should stay on queue.

Comment: Are you using NavigationController with this ViewControllers?

Comment: No i did not use any NavigationController. Actually i am new and will be happy if you explain it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the other answer here you can use

```
navigationController.viewControllers.remove(at: 1)
```

Edit:

You can use UINavigationController to control the stack of your ViewControllers.

```
let viewControllerA = UIViewController()
let viewControllerB = UIViewController()
let viewControllerC = UIViewController()
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewControllerA)
navigationController.pushViewController(viewControllerB, animated: true)
navigationController.pushViewController(viewControllerC, animated: true)
// Remove B
navigationController.viewControllers.remove(at: 1)
```

Comment: I can't apply this. It is probably my bad but let me explain myself in details. I present a view controller and when i am done with there i go another one. There is a timer and when timer is finished, i go back to previous one but by creating new. I go A -> B and when i am done with B i go to C. There is a timer in C and when it is finished I go back to B but creating new one not by dismissing C. And i want the old B to dismiss when i first go in C. I hope it is clear because im in trouble with this issue :D

Comment: OK. I actually did it on another project but in my project when i go to the C view controller it says nil value of IB outlet or something. It cannot find IB outlet. Do you have any idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends a little on how you are doing your navigation. If you are using a navigation controller, you can access the array of view controllers and manipulate that directly. For example,

```
navigationController.viewControllers.popLast() //removes the last view controller and gives you a reference to it if you need.
```

If you are using segues, you could segue back to viewController A before moving to C.

You can also manipulate the viewController stack in other ways using this.

You can also ask a view controller to dismiss itself using self.dismiss(animated: true).

If you are interested, I find Coordinator Pattern a really good way to solve a lot of navigation issues is iOS.

If you want to post some code, I can take a closer look at it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use presentingViewController property of UIViewController to access VC that presented this VC. This way u can dismiss previous VC.

```
/// lets present vc2 from vc 1
let vc1 = UIViewController()
let vc2 = UIViewController()
vc1.present(vc2, animated: true)
        
/// presentingViewController of vc2 will be vc1, and it will dismiss if presented modally.
vc2.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)
```

Comment: Can you pls explain this in details? Are these codes in a view controller?

Comment: UIViewController class has 2 useful properties:
1) presentingViewController - the view controller that presented this view controller. In other words - it's parent in navigation hierarchy. If your VC is presented modally - you will access VC that presented your VC, if not - this property will be nil.
2) presentedViewController - the view controller that is presented by this view controller. If you presented some VC from your VC - you will get it's reference, if not - this property will be nil.
Those properties can be accessed from any UIViewController or its subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

if you use navigation controller:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    func replaceCurrentVC(with vc: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        var allVC = viewControllers
        allVC[allVC.count - 1] = vc
        setViewControllers(allVC, animated: animated)
    }
}
```